# The probability of leaving an umbrella in specific store

Tags: probability

A man with an umbrella visits three stores. In each store, the probability of leaving the umbrella is $\frac{1}{4}$. If the man did leave his umbrella, what is the probability that he left it in store 1, 2, and 3 respectively?

This is my thoughts on the problem. Since the probaility of not leaving the umbrella in a given store is $\frac{3}{4}$, the probability of leaving it in store $j$ can be written as 1 - $(\frac{3}{4})^j$. My problem now is that I don't know how to calculate the conditional probabilities.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: by the way it's not 'forget', it's 'leave the umbrella' .

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: Is it ungrammatical to say "forget umbrella"?

Comment: Yes: 'forget' means you used to know something and now you don't. If you have misplaced an item you have left it, not forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the only way the man could have left his umbrella in the $k^\text{th}$ store is if he kept his umbrella in the first $(k-1)$ stores, then left it in the $k^{\text{th}}$ store. Hence, for each $k \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
&\text{Pr}[\text{man left it in the $k^\text{th}$ store} \mid \text{man left it in 1 of the 4 stores}] \\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}[\text{man left it in the $k^\text{th}$ store  AND man left it in 1 of the 4 stores}]}{\text{Pr}[\text{man left it in 1 of the 4 stores}]} \\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}[\text{man left it in the $k^\text{th}$ store}]}{1 - \text{Pr}[\text{man never left it in any of the 4 stores}]} \\
&= \frac{(\frac{3}{4})^{k-1}(\frac{1}{4})}{1 - (\frac{1}{4})^4} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: That was my first approach, but I calculated the probabilities for the specific stores incorrectly. With your answer and @jonnytan999 I've managed to get it right!

Comment: I have to take off my hat to you. I have to say, you type fast, and also this is a generalization, not like mine... Anyway, well done, user1176517!

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is not be formal. 
The probability for leaving the umbrella in the 1st store is $1/4$
The probability for leaving the umbrella in the 2nd store is $3/4*1/4=3/16$
Why? $3/4$ is achieved by the probability of the umbrella being still with the man when he enters the second house. $1/4$ is the probability that he will leave the umbrella there. 
I will leave you to calculate the answer for the last store. Spoiler provided.

> $3/4*3/4*1/4=9/64$