# A man forgets his umbrella to a store with a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. What is the probability for the umbrella being left in the store $i$ ?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The following solved problem is in our course material but I'm having a trouble understanding a part of it:

An absent-minded man forgets his umbrella to a store with a probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. One day, after visiting four stores, he realizes he had forgotten his umbrella. What is the probability for the umbrella being left in the store $i$ ?

$ A_i $= " the umbrella has been left in the store $i$ ", $i=1,2,3,4$

$ B $= " the umbrella has been forgotten to the store "

Now

$P(A_1)=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{64}{256}, \quad P(A_2)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{16}=\frac{48}{256}, $

$P(A_3)=(\frac{3}{4})^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{9}{64}=\frac{36}{256}, \quad P(A_4)=(\frac{3}{4})^3\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{27}{256}.$

Since $A_i \subset B$ for every $i$, $P(B|A_i)=1$ for every $i$. Now

$\sum^4_{k=1}P(A_k)=\frac{64}{256}+\frac{48}{256}+\frac{36}{256}+\frac{27}{256}=\frac{175}{256}$

and with Bayes' theorem we get

$P(A_i|B)=\frac{P(A_i)P(B|A_i)}{\sum^4_{k=1}P(A_k)P(B|A_k)}=\frac{P(A_i)}{\sum^4_{k=1}P(A_k)}=\frac{256}{175}P(A_i)$

for every $i=1,2,3,4$.

The probability of the umbrella being left in the store 1 is $P(A_1)=\frac{1}{4}=\frac{64}{256}$ but where do we get the $\frac{3}{4}$ in $P(A_2)=\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{16}=\frac{48}{256}$? And why do we multiply the $\frac{3}{4}$ with the probability of the umbrella being forgotten and also put it to the power in $P(A_3)$ and $P(A_4)$?

I know that there is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791379/the-probability-of-leaving-an-umbrella-in-specific-store) but I'm confused by the solutions.

Comment: In order to be left in the second store, the umbrella must first not be left in the first.  The probability of that is $1-\frac 14=\frac 34$

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your answer! I think I understand now how we got the $\frac{3}{4}$ but however, I still don't get why it is raised to the power in $P(A_3)=(\frac{3}{4})^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}$ and $P(A_4)=(\frac{3}{4})^3 \cdot \frac{1}{4}$? I mean, why is it not now $P(A_3)=\frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4}$ since now, in order for the umbrella to be left in the third store, it must not be left in the first and second store and $1-\frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 = \frac{2}{4}$?

Comment: The probability that umbrella was not left in the first and second store is $\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{4}$ because you need these two events happen in sequence (dependent events).

Comment: In order to be left in the third store, the umbrella must not be left in the first store AND it must not be left in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of not leaving it in the first store multiplied by the probability of not leaving it in the second store is (3/4)•(3/4), which then multiplied by the probability of leaving it in the 3rd store (1/4) gives the 3rd term.

Answer (score 0):

The event $A_2$ happening means that the person got to the second store without forgetting his umbrella at the first.

Let's mark with $C_i$ the event "the person would have forgotten his umbrella at store $i$, provided he had his umbrella with him", than the statement of the question means $C_1=C_2=C_3=C_4$.
So now we have $A_2 = A_1^\complement \cap C_2$. Also, by the definition of $C_i$ it's clear that $A_1$ and $C_2$ are independent, and thus $P(A_2)=P(A_1^\complement \cap C_2)=P(A_1^\complement)P(C_2)=(1-\frac{1}{4})\cdot\frac{1}{4}$.

By similiar arguments we can get $P(A_3)=P((A_1 \cup A_2)^\complement\cap C_3)$ and $P(A_4)$.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. $$P(A_3)=P(A_1^{\complement}\cap A_2^{\complement}\cap A_3)=P(A_1^{\complement})P(A_2^{\complement}\mid A_1^{\complement})P(A_3\mid A_1^{\complement}\cap A_2^{\complement})=\frac34\frac34\frac14$$